# Trying to get an output equal to my inline style with styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have written a code and included an inline style that works fine but i can't seem to do it with styled components. This is the code i want to convert to styled components;

```
     class NavbarLink extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const isActive = this.props.location.pathname.includes(this.props.path);
    return (
      <NavItem
        className="nav-item-padding-one-half"
        style={{
          borderBottom: isActive ? 'solid 2px var(--color-green)' : '',
        }}
      >
        <NavLink
          className={`${isActive ? 'nav-link-active' : null} nav-link`}
          to={this.props.path}
          onClick={() => this.props.onItemClicked()}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </NavLink>
      </NavItem>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
const BorderedDiv = styled.div`
  borderBottom: ${isActive ? "solid 2px var(--color-green)" : ''};
`;

<BorderedDiv>This is your bordered div</BorderedDiv>
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I have edited the post with the whole code. can you please review it and help?

Comment: Sure, can you please share the codesandbox link or code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `props` object of `styled-components`.

You should construct a styled-components's component as this,

```
export const NavItem = styled.div`
borderBottom: ${(props) => props.isActive ? "solid 2px var(--color-green)" : ''};
`
```

Use this component as,

```
import {NavItem} from './styles'; // if styled-component in another file 
<NavItem isActive> 
// your code here
...
</NavItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

> syntax :-

```
  const BorderedComp = styled.div`borderBottom :${isActive ? 'solid 2px var(--color-green'):'',};  `;
```

> use This Component as

```
<BorderedComp> This is Bordered Component </BorderedComp>
```